# Fixtures ignores my model relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, fixtures

I am leaving RSpec and starting using Test::Unit and Fixtures.
Please, what's wrong with my relations?

I have relation

```
def class InputSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :input_units
end
```

#### input_set_test.rb

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class InputSetTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'fixture is valid' do
    input_set = input_sets(:one)
    assert input_set.valid?
  end
end
```

#### Fixtures:

```
# input_sets.yml
one:
  name: 'Kalkulacia 1'
  input_units: product_1    <<<------- this is causing the problem

# input_units.yml
product_1:
  data: {val1: 'test', val2: 'test'}
  kind: 'product'
```

I run `rake test` and see error:

```
1) Error:
InputSetTest#test_fixture_is_valid:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "input_units" of relation "input_sets" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "input_sets" ("name", "input_units", "created_at...
                                      ^
: INSERT INTO "input_sets" ("name", "input_units", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('Kalkulacia 1', 'product_1', '2014-03-09 09:43:40', '2014-03-09 09:43:40', 980190962)
```

Comment: try `input_units: [product_1]`

Comment: Why you're not using factories instead of fixtures ?

Comment: @astropanic I would like to use built-in features. That's why Test::Unit and Fixtures. Btw, I know Factory Girl, it's more sophisticated, but I want simpler tool instead.

Comment: I understand that, I don't like a gazillion of gems installed either, but simplicity is not always a good way. Maybe for now fixtures are simpler because of unserializing a YAML file etc... but when your project grows, and with them the tests, your fixtures becomes unmaintainable, you will end up in code duplication what is error prone and brings a big technical debt. And because FactoryGirl for example is not built in, it doesn't mean it is a bad tool.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across the same problem. You might need to add the corresponding relation in the `InputUnit` model:

```
# input_unit.rb
class InputUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :input_unit_set
end
```